# How to get new coordinates of scene

Tags: java, javafx

How to get new coordinates of scene when the window of my application change position in screen.

I tryed to use it:

```
scene.windowProperty().addListener((val, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("X " + newValue.getX());
    System.out.println("Y " + newValue.getY());
});
```

But it not work.

Comment: Add listeners to the window’s [x property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#xProperty) and [y property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#yProperty), rather than listening to the window property itself.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [xProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#xProperty--) and [yProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#yProperty--)

```
scene.xProperty().addListener((val, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("X " + newVal));
scene.yProperty().addListener((val, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("Y " + newVal));
```